# Convert Python list of dicts to mapping of key to rest of dict

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following list:

```
l = [
    {"a": 10, "b": 100, "c": 100},
    {"a": 20, "b": 100, "c": 100},
    {"a": 30, "b": 100, "c": 100},
]
```

I know `"a"` is unique in each item:

```
assert len({x["a"] for x in l}) == len(l)
```

I want to generate a mapping of the `"a"` value to the rest of each item so my end result is the following dictionary:

```
{
    10: {"b": 100, "c": 100},
    20: {"b": 100, "c": 100},
    30: {"b": 100, "c": 100},
}
```

So far I've come up with the following:

```
{x["a"]: {k: v for k, v in x.items() if k != "a"} for x in l}
```

Is this the best way to write this? Or is there a better way or a built in function that I'm missing?

Comment: That looks pretty good.

Comment: Seems good to me - it looks pretty straightforward as dict comprehensions go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `dict.pop` is what you want?

```py
out = {d.pop('a'): d for d in l}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{10: {'b': 100, 'c': 100}, 20: {'b': 100, 'c': 100}, 30: {'b': 100, 'c': 100}}
```

Comment: `in l` should be `in l.values()`

Comment: @Barmar l is a list

Comment: Oops, I was looking at the result.